# Compiling C code from terminal, returns fatal error?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I'm learning about static and shared libraries under linux, and I've hit a problem for which I can't find a solution.
So, this is my /folder ls:

> user@Project:~/7.1$ ls
>
> > history           main.c        oduzmi.c
> >     podijeli.o  potenciraj.c  zbroji.o libmathsimple.a   main.o
> >     oduzmi.o    pomnozi.c   potenciraj.o libpotenciraj.so  mathsimple.h 
> >     podijeli.c  pomnozi.o   zbroji.c

Now at this point i try to compile my main.c which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mathsimple.h>
int main(void)
{

  int a,b;
  printf("Unesi a:\n");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("Unesi b:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&b);
  zbroji(a,b);
  oduzmi(a,b);

return 0;
}
```

When I do ./main.c I get:

```
./main.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./main.c: line 4: `int main(void)'
```

EDIT: 
I removed `mathsimple.h` and I got the same output. The previous mistake with `libmathsimple.a` was repaired, thank you for your advices.

P.S. All permissions are set. Is it possible that I am forgetting to include something somewhere??

Comment: `#include <libmathsimple.a>` are you trying to include a library as if it was a header file? Looks terribly wrong.

Comment: Ugh... Ugggghhh... go back a step. You need to understand what the difference between code and an executable is. This is serious.

Comment: It is not related to be on a terminal; you'll get the same errors with other ways of compiling your program.

Comment: @ouah yes, I know now that it's wrong, I was so frustrated that I included it inside the main.c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile it!

Try `man gcc` to get details

Answer (score 1):

The errors attributed to line 4 are a consequence of earlier problems in your file.

First, there are [two forms of `#include` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx), one using `<` and `>` to enclose a name, and the other using double quotes.  When a file to be included is in the working directory rather than in a library directory, use double quotes.

Secondly, a binary file like `libmathsimple.a` is  previously-compiled and will look like junk to the C compiler.  Instead, when you link your .o files use a `-l` option to mention `libmathsimple.a`, probably like `-lmathsimple`.

Comment: The '#' character for most (all?) shells is a comment. So it bangs into line 4 and gives up

Comment: @EdHeal so how should I include stdio.h?

Comment: @Nebbs - You need to compile the code!

Comment: @EdHeal - I'm sorry but so far I haven't received an answer. As soon as I receive it I will accept it. The closest advice was jwpat7, for which I upvoted.

Comment: @Nebbs - Compile it `gcc main.c`. Run it `.\a.out`

Comment: Very well, Ed. Did that and it returns undefined reference to zbroji() nad oduzmi(). Nonetheless I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Nebbs - Guess you need to link it to the library - mee the manual page for `gcc`